# How do I migrate my son's Windows 7 profile to a new Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, migration, user-profiles

My son has a computer on our home network that he has all set up with his links, settings, etc.

His grandfather sent us a new computer.

How can I move his user profile from the older machine to the new machine?

Both machines use Windows 7.  Both machines are on our workgroup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try "Easy Transfer". I just did it from my desktop to my laptop. Worked like a charm. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

Comment: Push the Easy button.

Answer (score 3):

[Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-NZ/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer), come with Windows 7. You can find it by typing in the name in the Start Menu.

It's a pretty easy Wizard. Pick "this is my old PC" on the current PC and it will scan for profiles. Deselect any you don't want to transfer (you can also select any misc files your want to transfer with the profile.)

Save the profile (I think it stores it as a .mig file) on an external drive then just double click that file on the new PC to start the transfer (or open up easy transfer and find the file.)